# Injection causing incompletely-constructed object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have the following super basic bean set up:

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public JobState jobState() {
  return new JobState();
}

public static class JobState {
  public final Map<String, PathData> paths = new HashMap<>();
}

public static class PathData {
  public final Path path;
  public final boolean downloaded;

  public PathData(final Path path, final boolean downloaded) {
    this.path = path;
    this.downloaded = downloaded;
  }
}
```

Then, somewhere else in my code, I have a tasklet factory like so:

```
@Bean
public Function<DownloadConfig, Tasklet> downloadTaskletFactory(final JobState jobState) {
  return config ->
      (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
        // [...]
        jobState.paths.put(...);
      };
}
```

However, when this runs, while `jobState` is not `null`, `jobState.paths` is. I'm not sure how exactly this would be possible, unless Spring is completely replacing my `JobState` class with a mock or something?

Comment: Have you tried to make your `downloadTaskletFactory` bean job scoped as well?

Comment: `Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.downloadTaskletFactory': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope`